# Как я могу вызвать стрелочную функцию в JS?

Tags: javascript

Пример стрелочной функции которую нужно вызвать в другом месте.
Как вызвать ее в другом месте или преобразовать в обычную?

```
for (const select of selects) {
    select.addEventListener('change', function () {
        console.log("Test");
    });
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Во-первых, в показанном коде нет стрелочной функции. Во-вторых, в каком таком другом месте? Что мешает поместить её в переменную или объявить глобально для последующего использования?

Comment: Я всегда думал что это то же стрелочная функция )

Comment: а что в таком случае `() => {}` ?

Comment: Исправил код, там был цикл еще for

Comment: Хочу вызвать в другой функции этот код, но не могу понять как

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function yoyo() {
    console.log("Test");
}

for (const select of selects) {
    select.addEventListener('change', yoyo);
}

// отдельно тоже работает
yoyo();
yoyo();
yoyo();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!